# How do I get difference between two dates of unknown format in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I get a date as String from server like this: `2017-01-23T16:08:45.742Z`. I want to find the difference in days, between this and the current date (or precisely, current time). I could just extract date alone (without time) and check, but I'd need a precise answer based on provided time & current time.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: What makes you think that's an unknown format?  It's precisely the format that the `Date` object in JavaScript unambiguously understands.

Comment: That date format looks like ISO 8601.

Comment: @jmargolisvt and @JamesThorpe I could see that's the proper date format in JS. However I was confused because when I tried that format in online JS date format tester I ran into an error: `Illegal pattern character T`

Comment: All the answers were correct, except for a minor change. When I tried to subtract the dates I ran into an error: `The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type.` I found a way to work around this issue from here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5710

Answer (score 1):

Should be easy....

```js
var dateFromServer = '2017-01-23T16:08:45.742Z'
var msInDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
var difference = (new Date(dateFromServer) - Date.now()) / msInDay
document.write('difference = ' + difference + ' days')
```

Answer (score 0):

That date format looks like ISO_8061. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Use the Date object to get the difference between today and the other date in milliseconds, then divide by the number of milliseconds in a day.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

The code below can be condensed into a single line but I wanted to be explicit.

```js
let date = "2017-01-23T16:08:45.742Z";

let d1 = new Date(date); // given date

let today = new Date(); // today's date

let diff = (d1 - today); // difference in milliseconds

let days = diff / 8.64e+7; // divide difference by 1 day in milliseconds

console.log(days)
```

Answer (score 0):

Point of clarification: if I understand you correctly, you're actually trying to get the difference between two dates of **different** formats, not two dates of **unknown** formats. That's way easier.

Further, it looks like your server string is already stored in ISO format, which again makes this way easier.

I'd recommend looking at the [JavaScript Date object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp). I believe in this case your best bet would be something like this:

```
// Your string from the server
var data_from_server = '2017-01-23T16:08:45.742Z';

// Create a new Date() object using the ISO string provided by your server
var olddate = new Date(data_from_server);

// Create a new empty Date() object, which should default to the current time
var currentdate = new Date();

// Subtract the two
var dif = currentdate.getTime() - olddate.getTime();

// Alert the result
alert(dif);
```